# How to connect to Vault server

Tags: devops

I wanted to give a try to [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), so I configured `VAULT_ADDR` as:

```
$ echo $VAULT_ADDR 
http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

then I started vault in dev mode (`vault server -dev`) and everything was ok, I was able to connect to the server.

Then I wrote a really simple config file:

```
$ cat vault.config 
backend "inmem"

listener "tcp" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

disable_mlock = true
```

and I restarted the server with `vault server -config=vault.config`, but then when I connect to the server, I get:

```
$ vault status
Error checking seal status: Get http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Is there something wrong in my config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the back end like this:

```
backend "inmem" {}
```

otherwise there is a problem parsing the listener clause.