# Error checking seal status while connecting to Vault Docker

Tags: docker, devops, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to run vault docker in server mode as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/vault/#running-vault-in-server-mode). This is the command I'm using to run vault

```
docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend": {"file": {"path": "/home/jwahba/PycharmProjects/work/vault/vault.json"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h"}' vault server
```

And this is the vault.json configuration file

```
storage "inmem" {}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

disable_mlock = true
```

The container comes up successfully.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
55100205d2ab        vault               "docker-entrypoint..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        8200/tcp            stoic_blackwell
```

However, when I try to execute

```
 docker exec stoic_blackwell vault status
```

I get the below error:

```
Error checking seal status: Get https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193952/how-to-connect-to-vault-server) but unfortunately I couldn't figure out what I misconfigured.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What do the container logs output?

Comment: @BMitch Thanks for your reply. Please find below output from docker logs command. There's nothing much there
==> Vault server configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: true
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v0.10.1
             Version Sha: 756fdc4587350daf1c65b93647b2cc31a6f119cd

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG` parameter specifies the configuration of your Vault; using the `{"backend": {"file":` annotation you set a file backend as the storage one.

So, in `VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG` you should directly include what you wrote in your configuration file (vault.json).

*Sidenote: The configuration file that you wrote is in HCL language, not json.*

Answer (score 0):

Please try it with below command,

```
vault status -tls-skip-verify
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow kalairaj. If you think your answer does not provide a full solution to the question and it just contains some guidance, please send it as comment from now on.