# I'm trying to unseal vault using ansible. But I'm getting connection refused error

Tags: ansible, command-line-interface, hashicorp-vault

It worked a few days back, i even checked similar problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193952/how-to-connect-to-vault-server)
I tried to add the environment variables and everything, my hcl file aslo is not a problem as far as i know

hcl file is

```
storage "file" {
path = "/home/***/vault/"
}

listener "tcp" {
address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
tls_disable = 1
}
```

my unseal.yml looks like this

```
---
- name: Removing login and putting to another file
  shell: sed -n '7p' keys.txt > login.txt

- name: Remove all lines other than the keys
  shell: sed '6,$d' keys.txt > temp.txt

- name: Extracting the keys 
  shell: cut -c15- temp.txt > unseal_keys.txt

- name: Deleting unnecessary files
  shell: rm temp.txt

- name: Unsealing the vault
  environment: 
    VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
  shell: vault operator unseal $(awk 'NR==1' unseal_keys.txt)

- name: Unsealing the vault
  environment: 
    VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
  shell: vault operator unseal $(awk 'NR==2' unseal_keys.txt)

- name: Unsealing the vault
  environment: 
    VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
  shell: vault operator unseal $(awk 'NR==3' unseal_keys.txt)
  register: check

- debug: var=check.stdout_lines

- name: Login
  environment: 
    VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
  shell: vault login $(sed 's/Initial Root Token://; s/ //' login.txt)
  register: checkLogin

- debug: var=checkLogin.stdout_lines
```

My start-server.yml looks like this

```
---
#- name: Disable mlock 
#  shell: sudo setcap cap_ipc_lock=+ep $(readlink -f $(which vault))
#  shell: LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

- name: Start vault service
  systemd:
    state: started
    name: vault
    daemon_reload: yes
  environment: 
    VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
  become: true

- pause:
    seconds: 15
```

This the error shown.

```
fatal: [europa]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "vault operator unseal $(awk 'NR==1' unseal_keys.txt)", "delta": "0:00:00.049258", "end": "2019-09-17 12:25:48.987789", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-09-17 12:25:48.938531", "stderr": "Error unsealing: Put http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused", "stderr_lines": ["Error unsealing: Put http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

This is the main error

```
"Error unsealing: Put http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused", "stderr_lines": ["Error unsealing: Put http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused"
```

Comment: Can you check if port 8200 is open ?

Comment: Yeah, i just checked, it looks it's not open. i tried the command  netstat -vatn to chek and there was no port 8200 to open

Comment: Open port and then try

Comment: I opened the port, but the vault server is not starting up.
I tried it in another remote system, it works

Answer (score 0):

> "Error unsealing: Put http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused"

As it is showing connection refused, most probably your vault service is not running.

Other thing which I can suggest is that you can make a script named unseal_vault.sh and can use that script to unseal your vault instead of repeating same tasks in your playbook.

Below is a script which I use in my setup to unseal vault.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assumptions: vault is already initialized 

# Fetching first three keys to unseal the vault
KEY_1=$(cat keys.log | grep 'Unseal Key 1' | awk '{print $4}')
KEY_2=$(cat keys.log | grep 'Unseal Key 2' | awk '{print $4}')
KEY_3=$(cat keys.log | grep 'Unseal Key 3' | awk '{print $4}')

# Unseal using first key
curl --silent -X PUT \
  http://192.*.*.*:8200/v1/sys/unseal \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "key": "'$KEY_1'"
}'

# Unseal using second key
curl --silent -X PUT \
  http://192.*.*.*:8200/v1/sys/unseal \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "key": "'$KEY_2'"
}'

# Unseal using third key
curl --silent  -X PUT \
  http://192.*.*.*:8200/v1/sys/unseal \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "key": "'$KEY_3'"
}'
```

And you can run this script using a single task in ansible.